# Commercial support for CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, licenses

As you know CentOS is taken over by RedHat, so i boils out couple of points as mentioned here.

- Will CentOS remain complete free as it was(is) before(now)?
- Can we expect upgrades of CentOS in future, as and when RHEL new version is released.?
- Will RHEL make it enterprise version?

What are the organizations that provide commercial support for CentOS? 
Redhat has said they are not going to provide commercial support for CentOS.

Comment: Any answers would be purely speculative: voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

[ZDnet](http://www.zdnet.com/red-hat-incorporates-free-red-hat-clone-centos-7000024907/) reports that CentOS will remain free:

> If your company is already using CentOS... Do Not Freak Out. Red Hat
>   is not going to start charging you for using CentOS. CentOS will
>   continue to be an independent distribution with community, not paid,
>   support.

[Wired](http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2014/01/redhat-centos/) reports that the move will allow CentOS the ability to fix bugs in public view without threat of lawsuit from RedHat:

> Although several CentOS developers will join the Red Hat payroll, they
>   won’t be part of the Red Hat Enterprise Linux team, according to an
>   announcement on the CentOS mailing list. The move is expected to
>   confer several advantages, such as the ability to bring its process
>   for finding and fixing bugs into public view without fear of legal
>   reprisals from Red Hat.

[RedHat](http://www.redhat.com/about/news/press-archive/2014/1/red-hat-and-centos-join-forces) says that CentOS will still draw on RHEL but will be more flexible ("open to variation"):

> CentOS, a community-supported and produced Linux distribution that
>   draws on Red Hat Enterprise Linux and other open source technologies
>   to provide a platform that's open to variation. CentOS provides a base
>   for community adoption and integration of open source cloud, storage,
>   network, and infrastructure technologies on a Red Hat-based platform.