# Why would a large company opt for CentOS instead of RHEL

Tags: centos, rhel

**This question is on the financial and strategic motivation for a "large company" to choose CentOS over RHEL and is not directed specifically at Facebook.**

I just read [this article](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Facebook-systemd-2018).

The key takeaway is:

> Facebook is using CentOS 7 everywhere from hosts to containers.

What is the motivation for a company as large as Facebook to use CentOS instead of RHEL where they would get tier-1 level support and consulting contracts? If they have any issues then it has to go through the CentOS team which, [while pay-rolled by Red Hat, isn't part of the RHEL team](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118180/commercial-support-for-centos) and bugs will work their way up more slowly to get upstream.

You could argue that if they retain a contract with Red Hat for RHEL then they could just support bugs directly. I don't know for sure but I don't think they would support CentOS bugs being reported directly as this isn't the same "product".

I would be very interested to understand their motivation and what advantage they perceive or realize through this choice.

Comment: Why pay when with an org like fb they can be self-supporting?  If a group can internally support, only paying when required - ie, wanting a commercially supported install of some big thing like a major db or a course management system or SIS, etc. but they will only support their system when it is running on distribution Redebwaretu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for why Facebook chose to go with Linux and CentOS, you can find them talking about it.

From a presentation of their own - [Running CentOS on the Facebook fleet](https://www.slideshare.net/DavideCavalca1/running-centos-on-the-facebook-fleet)

page 8 :

- We move fast ; opensource moves faster
- We don´t need to write everything ourselves
- Sharing our code means sharing the maintenance and have others extend it

page 9 : why CentOS:

- Stable releases
- Binary compatibility
- *[Frequent]* Security updates
- Mature and well understood tooling
- EPEL
- Close relationship with Fedora *[and RH]*

page 10:

- Backports from Fedora Rawhide for stuff we care about
- CentOS + FTL  = stable distro, moving fast

page 27:

- every two weeks we sync down the latest updates

Also, in my own experience, in the past when I went with Debian in consulting projects, and the two Universities and three ISPes were I worked, it was due to:

- having the know how;
- being heavily used and supported by a big user community;
- being pretty well documented;
- the malleability of the package management to save me work managing several systems and keeping them up-to-date - and having specific deb versions in my local repository of packages compiled by myself;
- not being a pain in the ass managing the bureaucratic side of licenses;
- the chance of highly customising it to my needs;
- it being slanted towards development, that I needed to do;
- it supporting well the hardware, and later on VMWare Enterprise;
- being well supported by devops tools;
- the availability of debugging tools;
- having the source code;
- being somewhat more stable than alternative distributions due to using more tested software and their unstable->testing->stable release cycle;
- having regular security updates, often faster than other distributions;
- having regularly new versions.

In many organisations they might have similar reasons for their OS of choice.

In my case, cost was never the most important factor. However I guess that in organisation that boasts having hundred of thousands of systems/containers, that will certainly play a more important role.